# Is it possible to perform row-wise tensor operations if two PyTorch tensors do not have the same size without using list comprehensions?

Tags: pytorch, tensor

This is a pretty specific usage case, but I'm hoping someone out there is more familiar with PyTorch tensors than I am and can help me speed this up.

I'm working on implementing a custom similarity metric for a neural network and have successfully gotten it to work, but it is incredibly slow to calculate. Each epoch takes about a minute to run, which simply isn't going to work with how I wanted to compare it with other metrics. So, I've been trying to utilize PyTorch tensors more effectively to speed things up, but haven't had much success.

Basically, I need to sum up the integers in the 'counts' tensor between the min and max indices specified in the 'min' and 'max' tensors for each sample and cluster combination.

As mentioned, my original implementation using loops took about a minute per epoch to run, but I did manage to reduce that to about 18-20 seconds using list comprehensions:

```
# counts has size (16, 100), max and min have size (2708, 7, 16)
data_mass = torch.sum(torch.tensor([[[torch.pow(torch.sum(counts[k][min[i][j][k]:max[i][j][k]+1]) / divisor, 2) for k in range(len(counts))] for j in range(len(min[i]))] for i in range(len(min))]), 2)
```

This feels super janky, and I've seen some clever things done with PyTorch functions, but I haven't been able to find anything yet that addresses quite what I want to do. Thanks in advance! I'm happy to clarify anything that may not be clear, I understand the use case is a bit convoluted.

EDIT: I'll try and break down the code snippet above and provide a minimal example. Examples of minimal inputs might look like the following:

'min' and 'max' are both 3-dimensional tensors of shape (num_samples, num_clusters, num_features), such as this one of size (2, 3, 4)

```
min = tensor([[[1, 2, 3, 1], 
               [2, 1, 1, 2],
               [1, 2, 2, 1]], 
              [[2, 3, 2, 1], 
               [3, 3, 1, 2],
               [1, 0, 2, 1]]])

max = tensor([[[3, 3, 4, 4], 
               [3, 2, 3, 4],
               [2, 4, 3, 2]], 
              [[4, 4, 3, 3], 
               [4, 4, 2, 3],
               [2, 1, 3, 2]]])
```

'counts' is a 2-dimensional tensor of size(num_features, num_bins),
so for this example we'll say size (4, 5)

```
counts = tensor([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
                 [2, 5, 3, 1, 1],
                 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
                 [2, 5, 3, 1, 1]])
```

The core part of the code snippet given above is the summation of the counts tensor between the values given by the min and max tensors for each pair of indices given at each index in max/min. For the first sample/cluster combo above:

```
mins = [1, 2, 3, 1]
maxes = [3, 3, 4, 4]

#Starting with feature #1 (leftmost element of min/max, top row of counts), 
    we sum the values in counts between the indices specified by min and max:
min_value = mins[0] = 1
max_value = maxes[0] = 3
counts[0] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

subset = counts[0][mins[0]:maxes[0]+1] = [2, 3, 4]
torch.sum(subset) = 9

#Second feature
min_value = mins[1] = 2
max_value = maxes[1] = 3
counts[1] = [2, 5, 3, 1, 1]

subset = counts[0][mins[0]:maxes[0]+1] = [3, 1]
torch.sum(subset) = 4
```

In my code snippet, I perform a few additional operations, but if we ignore those and just sum all the index pairs, the output will have the form

```
pre_sum_output = tensor([[[9, 4, 9, 10],
                          [7, 8, 9, 5]
                          [5, 5, 7, 8]],
                         [[12, 2, 7, 9],
                          [9, 2, 5, 4],
                          [5, 7, 7, 8]]])
```

Finally, I sum the output one final time along the third dimension:

```
data_mass = torch.sum(pre_sum_output, 2) = torch.tensor([[32, 39, 25],
                                                         [30, 20, 27]])
```

I then need to repeat this for every pair of mins and maxes in 'min' and 'max' (each [i][j][k]), hence the list comprehension above iterating through *i* and *j* to get each sample and cluster respectively.

Comment: Can you give a minimal example input and the expected output? Preferably also the output at each step of your posted code to make it easier to understand.

Comment: I've added a simple example and tried to do a better job illustrating the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By noticing that `torch.sum(counts[0][mins[0]:maxes[0]+1])` is equal to `cumsum[maxes[0]] - cumsum[mins[0]-1]` where `cumsum = torch.cumsum(counts[0])`, you can get rid of the loops like so:

```py
# Dim of sample, clusters, etc.
S, C, F, B = range(4)

# Copy min and max over bins
min = min.unsqueeze(B)
max = max.unsqueeze(B)

# Copy counts over samples and clusters
counts = counts.reshape(
    1,  # S
    1,  # C
    *counts.shape  # F x B
)

# Number of samples, clusters, etc.
ns, nc, nf, nb = min.size(S), min.size(C), min.size(F), counts.size(B)

# Calculate cumulative sum and copy over samples and clusters
cum_counts = counts.cumsum(dim=B).expand(ns, nc, nf, nb)

# Prevent index error when min index is 0
is_zero = min == 0
lo = (min - 1).masked_fill(is_zero, 0)

# Compute the contiguous sum from min to max (inclusive)
lo_sum = cum_counts.gather(dim=B, index=lo)
hi_sum = cum_counts.gather(dim=B, index=max)
sum_counts = torch.where(is_zero, hi_sum, hi_sum - lo_sum)

pre_sum_output = sum_counts.squeeze(B)
```

You can then sum over the 2nd dim to get `data_mass`.

Comment: You are an absolute wizard. This works perfectly and runs in a fraction of the time. I can actually get comparable results now, thanks a ton!